# htaccess rewrite to subdirectory with exceptions

Tags: .htaccess

I have setup my GoDaddy Shared Hosting account that no scripts should be run directly from server root - scripts start at least one subdir down. I also have subdomains which also fall in this category because it seems that my server simply rewrites the subdomains to selected folders.

```
/root
  wordpress
  drupal
  app1
  subdomains
     sub1
     sub2
     sub3
```

I decided that I want www.mydomain.com to launch wordpress - so after quite a bit of research on SO and testing some solutions - this is the htaccess that worked. Other solutions were causing a 500 server internal error which I assume is a limitation of my hosting plan.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.mydomain.com$ [NC,OR]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !wordpress/
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ wordpress/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

But now subdomains no longer work and from the server error message `The requested URL /wordpress/subdomains/sub1/ was not found on this server.` it is evident that my rewrite rules are kicking in for the subdomains.

I tried adding a `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !subdomains` befor the RewriteRule but didn't help.
Also `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d`-all rewrites stop working.

**How can I modify the rules so that specific directories/patterns should not be redirected? Or maybe if directory exists it shouldn't rewrite?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this *before* the rules that you have for wordpress:

```
RewriteRule ^subdomains - [L]
```

It should simply let requests that start with `/subdomains` pass through without doing any rewriting.

Answer (score 1):

Replace your Rewrite rule with this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ wordpress/$1 [L]
```

This will make sure `wordpress/` redirection is not done for any file or directory.